# Resteasy with Guice configuration issues

Tags: maven, jboss, guice, resteasy

I'm new to both Resteasy and Guice, but I'm having problems getting the simple tutorial to work.  Here are my relevant files.  I have reproduced the error below, but I have not seen anyone with the same problem as me.  I have gotten Resteasy to work without Guice, after adding the provided tag in pom for resteasy-jaxrs, but that seems to be not there with resteasy-guice.  I hope someone can please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

MyModule.java

```
package foo.guice;

import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.google.inject.Binder;
import foo.rest.Controller;

public class MyModule implements Module {
    @Override
    public void configure(final Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(Controller.class);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package foo.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

@Path("hello")
public class Controller
{
   @GET
   @Path("{name}")
   public String hello(@PathParam("name") final String name) {
      return "Hello " + name;
   }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.war</version>

    <name>FooBar</name>        

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jackson JSON library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RESTEasy libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For testing purposes --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>FooBar</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.guice.MyModule</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Setting up RESTEasy as in http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/Guice1.html -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is the output from server.log

```
11:14:14,410 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener] (MSC service thread 1-2) found module: foo.guice.MyModule
11:14:14,610 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) registering factory for foo.rest.Controller
11:14:14,612 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bar-1.0]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResourceFactory.registered(Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/InjectorFactory;)V
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:121) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:107) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:84) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor.processInjector(ModuleProcessor.java:41) [resteasy-guice-3.0.4.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:51) [resteasy-guice-3.0.4.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

11:14:14,679 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
11:14:14,680 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/bar-1.0] startup failed due to previous errors
11:14:14,695 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bar-1.0]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.triggerAnnotatedMethods(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:137) [resteasy-guice-3.0.4.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:132) [resteasy-guice-3.0.4.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

11:14:14,718 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/bar-1.0": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/bar-1.0": JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

11:14:14,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "bar-1.0.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/bar-1.0\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/bar-1.0\": JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
11:14:14,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment bar-1.0.war in 54ms
11:14:14,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/bar-1.0": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/bar-1.0": JBAS018040: Failed to start context
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for me, once I rolled resteasy back to 2.3.2.Final, it all worked, so um yea....

Comment: Do still have your pom around or remember which dependency you changed? Did you set it to 2.3.2.Final just for resteasy-guice? It also looks like Guice 2.0 is not in Maven central..